# Exception error - What exactly to correct. Magento 2.2 on localhost was fine

Tags: magento2.2, exception, frontend-error

I can access admin pannel (backend), but frontend `localhost/magento` will only display this.

I have run `compile, upgrade, clean and flush commands`.

Was working fine was only make changes to css styles. Looked in a few of the files but not clear what is wrong?

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 743


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 743

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, 'C:/xampp/htdocs...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-cms\Helper\Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-cms\Controller\Index\Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'bege1')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `after` and `before` attributes from `referenceContainer` in your `.xml`, clean the cache then refresh, it should work.

If you want to reorder your container, use the `move` attribute like this:

```
<move element="containerName" destination="destinationElementName" before="-"/>
```

Comment: cache has been refreshed/cleared.  what .xml file are you referring too?

Comment: you refresh the cache after removing these attributes, euhh the `xml` i dont know, check what you have changed recently, maybe in `default.xml` or in some layout module or ... you're the only one who knows what has been changed in your Magento

Comment: That's the thing - i haven't changed anything. This attribute doesn't exist in the 15+ i've looked in.  Thank you i'll keep searching, it's something more going on here.

Comment: Actually, @prince answer is correct. The thing is that there are MANY layout XML files you may need to look in, quite possibly more than 15.

Comment: thanks @Shawn Abramson, that's what I'm trying to explain to him but he says no, but im sure when he goes find these attributes he will tell me oh Prince it's true you were right and now it works and I'm happy :)

Comment: Indeed. There is simply a misplaced "after" attribute somewhere and he's gonna have to find it.